# How to send posts' name using WP_Query into a select custom field plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress

In the folder of mu-plugin I created a file, then created a function to query all posts with type "speaker", but I don't know, how to put them into a select box named "Speakers" which created with custom-field WordPress plugin.

This the function that I query all posts with type speaker:

```
function displayPosts()
{
$homepageSpeaker = new WP_Query(array(
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'post_type' => 'speaker'
));

while($homepageSpeaker->have_posts()) {
$homepageSpeaker->the_post();

// Add the id and name of each post in a select box named "Speakers"

}

}

add_action('admin_menu','displayPosts');
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want to have that select box?

A mu-plugin does not sound like the right place for that.

What plugin is the "custom-field WordPress plugin" you are using?
Likely they have a documentation how to add options to certain select fields.